# help on html, css, table error

Tags: html, css

i get error in opera error console for this line,

```
filter:alpha(opacity=99); opacity=0.99; MozOpacity=0.99;
```

am using it this way

what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change opacity=0.99; MozOpacity=0.99; to

```
opacity:0.99; -moz-opacity:0.99;
```

i.e:

```
<table  id="BannerTable" 
                cellpadding="0" 
                cellspacing="0" 
                border="0" 
                style="filter:alpha(opacity=99); opacity:0.99; -moz-opacity:0.99;display:block;"
                width="779"
                background="Ldi.JPG"    
                style="" 
                onclick="javascript:openLink();"
>
```

Comment: can you pls apply it to that table?

Comment: Added the sample table tag and edited MozOpacity to -moz-opacity

Answer (score 1):

The first semicolon ends the filter. Try commas instead:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=99), opacity=0.99, MozOpacity=0.99;
```

Comment: can you pls apply it to that table?

Answer (score 0):

@Smith: Try this instead --

```
opacity: 0.99;             /* Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome (WebKit) */
filter: alpha(opacity=99); /* IE */
```

Comment: can you pls apply i to tha table?